# "The system cannot find the file specified" en-parser-chunking.bin

Tags: java, apache, nlp, bin

I have two projects in my eclipse for sentence parsing with Apache Open NLP. One project is working fine. But for the other project I'm getting below error.

[image]

Here is my project structure, Both project has the "en-parser-chunking.bin" file.

[image]

OpenNLP project is working fine (I got that project from the internet). So I copied that "en-parser-chunking.bin" file from there and pasted it on my books application project also. But I'm getting above error. What happened to my code ? Is there any other way to import "en-parser-chunking.bin" file to my books application project ?

below is the code I use in books application

```
public void parserAction() throws Exception {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
    ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);
    Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
    Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(line, parser, 1);
    for (Parse p : topParses){
        //p.show();
        getNounPhrases(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put it into a Directory which is part of the classpath. in modern projects it is under `/src/main/resources/`. If you have copied it to this Location you can get the File with.

```
InputStream is =MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/en-parser-chunking.bin");
```

where *MyClass* is the name of your class

Comment: Hello Sir. How to copy my file to /src/main/resources/ directory ? I have bot used maven before.. is there any other way ?

Comment: @user8048032 Why it should not be possible to add files manually to your Project?

Comment: sir..I don't know how to access /src/main/resources/  directory. can you please tell me how to copy that file to this directory ?

Comment: @user8048032 this is only a example of the folde. That is the Name where we put such files in modern Project Settings using maven or gradle or such Tools. It can be every other Folder in your project, which is in the classpath

Comment: I'm new to java programming. How can I find what my class path is ?

Comment: @user8048032 That are very Basics sorry